# On whether the construction of a certain type of Algebras(over a given field) from Graphs , functorial

Tags: graph-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Definition 2.2 on Page 11 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1835.pdf  introduces an algebra (where the field is fixed) for every (finite) graph . My question is : Is this construction ,  of Leavitt Path algebras from graphs , functorial ? where as the source category we take the objects as "row finite" graphs and morphisms as Graph homomorphisms and as target category we take the category of algebras .

Comment: Read page 12 proposition 2.4